# table outer border excluding last row

Tags: css, wordpress

Is there a way to have a table, with only an outer border, but not include the bottom row. So the bottom border of the second last row makes it look like the final row. I can only use css as it's wordpress, so I can't change the html! See the picture:
[image]

The coupon code and update basket are actually the final row

***** EDIT *****
This is is the HTML (that I can't edit)

```
<table class="shop_table cart" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="product-name">Product</th>
            <th class="product-price">Price</th>
            <th class="product-quantity">Quantity</th>
            <th class="product-subtotal">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

                        <tr class="cart_item">

                    <td class="product-remove">
                        <a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/basket/?remove_item=02522a2b2726fb0a03bb19f2d8d9524d&amp;_wpnonce=967f1478b0" class="remove" title="Remove this item">×</a>                   </td>

                    <td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/shop//tedbaker/test-product-copy"><img width="180" height="135" src="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/TedBaker_TravelDocHolderCoral_5-180x135.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="TedBaker_TravelDocHolderCoral_5"></a>                  </td>

                    <td class="product-name">
                        <a href="http://uc.petekirkwood.co.uk/shop//tedbaker/test-product-copy">Test Product (Copy) </a>                    </td>

                    <td class="product-price">
                        <span class="amount">£10.00</span>                  </td>

                    <td class="product-quantity">
                        <div class="quantity"><input type="number" step="1" min="0" name="cart[02522a2b2726fb0a03bb19f2d8d9524d][qty]" value="3" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4"></div>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-subtotal">
                        <span class="amount">£30.00</span>                  </td>
                </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                                    <div class="coupon">

                        <label for="coupon_code">Coupon:</label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="Coupon code"> <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="Apply Coupon">


                    </div>

                <input type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="Update Basket">


                <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="967f1478b0"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/basket/?removed_item=1">         </td>
        </tr>

            </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border around the table won't be able to exclude the last row. You can remove that last row and replace it with another element (like a div or another table).

Or you could use this workaround:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr:first-child td,
table tr:last-child td {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:nth-last-child(n+2) td:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:nth-last-child(n+2) td:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xbht5861/)

## EDIT based on comments

I added the table header row.

I found out that `border-collapse: collapse` and `border-radius` don't go together. Instead, you'll need to add `cellspacing="0"` to the HTML tag of your table.

```
table {
    /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
    /* border-collapse and rounded borders
    don't go togehter, instead add
    cellspacing="0" to your table*/
}
table tr:first-child th { /* first row */
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:nth-last-child(2) td { /* second last row */
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table tr:nth-last-child(n+2) td:first-child,
table thead tr th:first-child { /* all left cells, expect the last */
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:nth-last-child(n+2) td:last-child, 
table thead tr th:last-child { /* all right cells, expect the last */
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:first-child th:first-child { /* cell left top */
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
table tr:first-child th:last-child { /* cell right top */
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}
table tr:nth-last-child(2) td:first-child { /* cell left bottom */
    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
table tr:nth-last-child(2) td:last-child { /* cell right bottom */
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

[**UPDATED Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xbht5861/2/)
[Fiddle with your exact HTML structure](http://jsfiddle.net/xbht5861/3/)

Comment: Thanks - that almost works, except there is a table header row which knocks it off. Also the top border and second last row need rounded corners.

Comment: In your question you don't mention a table header, please add your HTML to the OP.

Comment: sorry about that. I've added the html now.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the second-last item

```
tr:nth-first-child {/*the first item*/
  border-bottom: 2px solid black
}
tr:nth-last-child(2) { /*the second-last item*/
  border-bottom: 2px solid black
}
tr:not(:last-child){/* all but not the last */
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black
}
```